# Compile error scala project

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, sbt

I'm taking the coursera scala course. I downloaded the sample project, but I can not compile it. Giving me error when I run the console command.

build.sbt:

```
name := course.value + "-" + assignment.value

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation")

// grading libraries
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % Test

// for funsets
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4"

resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"

// include the common dir
commonSourcePackages += "common"

courseId := "bRPXgjY9EeW6RApRXdjJPw"
```

Error:

```
> console
[info] Updating root
[info] Resolved root dependencies
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:coursierResolution for the full output.
[error] (*:coursierResolution) coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 1 error(s) in dependency resolution:
[error]   org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:2.2.4:
[error]     not found:
[error]       /Users/joaonobre/.ivy2/local/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/2.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]       /Users/joaonobre/.sbt/preloaded/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/2.2.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]       /Users/joaonobre/.sbt/preloaded/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/2.2.4/scalatest_2.12-2.2.4.pom
[error]       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/2.2.4/scalatest_2.12-2.2.4.pom
[error]       http://repo.artima.com/releases/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/2.2.4/scalatest_2.12-2.2.4.pom
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 22, 2017 4:16:17 PM

scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.4 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the course uses Scala 2.12? The error tell you, that it cannot resolve dependency on scalatest-2.2.4 for Scala 2.12 (probably because only scalatest-3.+ is available for 2.12). At the same time you're using junit. So please provide a link to the course, then I can check what are differences with the official setup instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @laughedelic, Scala 2.12 does not have scalatest-2.2.4. As a result, sbt cannot find the related scalatest pom file. You can pick any of the versions mentioned [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/).

For instance, try changing scalaTestDependency version to 3.0.5 in the CommonBuild.scala file

```
lazy val scalaTestDependency = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
```

Here is the course [link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/home/welcome) (Practice Programming Assignment of Week1)